# Classe Bean não foi encontrada - JavaWeb

Tags: jpa, crud

Boa noite, estou fazendo meu tcc em Java Web e fazendo a persistência de dados com JPA e Hibernete. Fiz o CRUD aparentemente está certo, mas quando clico no botão cadastrar ele dá esse erro.

```
action="#{empresaController.incluir()}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'empresaController' resolved to null
```

Creio eu que que não está encontrando a minha classe `empresaController`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EmpresaController extends BaseController<Empresa>{

    public EmpresaController() {
        super(Empresa.class);
        this.dao = new EmpresaDao();
    }

    @Override
    public void limpar() {
        this.objeto = new Empresa();

    }
    @Override
    public String incluir() {
        return super.incluir(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta colocando o código da classe `empresaController`?

Comment: editado ja com o código

Comment: Não tenho uma resposta, mas talvez [esse thread no GUJ](http://www.guj.com.br/java/294982-target-unreachable-identifier--resolved-to-null) seja útil para ajudar a identificar o problema. (Você importou esse `ManagedBean` de `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`?)

Comment: sim é importado do javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean